# why swagger-maven-plugin changed my output to "application/xhtml+xml"?

Tags: java, tomcat, swagger, swagger-maven-plugin

I am new to swagger-maven-plugin and I added it to pom.xml, 
the swagger.json was generated but all my REST api is not working anymore

I found that in the response header "content type" was changed to application/xhtml+xml
and all former returned json data now became xml 
like

```
<JSONObject xmlns=""><preferences><booking><qualityManual></qualityManual>
```

while before it was

```
{"preferences":{"booking":{"qualityManual":{},
```

can anyone help? Did I mis-configed something?

I am using version 3.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is I shouldn't add below to pom file:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

while they shouldn't be there and actually I just need to config the plugin in the plugin section.